# filter for date values in a table

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I have this sub:

```
Sub standardfilter()
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tabelle1")
        
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=Date()", Operator:=xlAnd
        
        Range("Tabelle1").Sort Key1:=Range("E5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        

End Sub
```

which is connected to a command button which when executed should first filter for dates which are today or in the future and then filter another date column in ascending order. The problem is that there is no data shown if I only execute the first filter with `Criteria1:=">=Date()"` whereby there is data from today or in the future.

The excel table looks like this:
[image]

"Gremium" is the event name "Gremientermin" the event's date and "Frist" is the date for a specific work flow within the process for that event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```vb
tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Date), Operator:=xlAnd
```

In this case the date is converted to its numeric equivalent - which is recognized as criteria independent of the systems language

Comment: A good solution! :)