# VBA - Filter between dates - well displayed in Excel filter but no data returned

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA code I added below code to filter between 2 dates (for example from 01/01/2023 to 31/12/2023).

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AG1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Day(periodStart) & "/" & Month(periodStart) & "/" & Year(periodStart), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:= _
    "<=" & Day(periodEnd) & "/" & Month(periodEnd) & "/" & Year(periodEnd)
```

In Excel no data returned by the filter even if there are such data.
If we check the filter we can see right values... and when we validate the filter without any modification we see data we were waiting from.

[Excel screens illustrating my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MtR4.png)

I tried to use different syntaxes I found in others posts to set the filter but in all cases I've got the same issue: right filter set but no data displayed until I go in the Excel filter and validate it without any modification.

As everything seems being fine I don't know what to do to solve my issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try using the value of date - s. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219141/16578424

Comment: Pls put this line after autofiltering: `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.filters(1).Criteria1, ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.filters(1).Criteria2` . What did you get in the immediate window?

Answer (score 3):

Dates are a little bit tricky. Dates are internally stored as Double values, with the integer part representing the Date (number of days since 1.1.1900) and the fraction as time (0.5 = noon, 0.75 = 6pm).

If you enter the date filter manually in Excel, it is displaying the date in the format of your regional settings, however, internally the filter dates are stored as numbers representing that date. You can check that with the debugger:

[image]

So instead of writing strings as criteria, simply write the number itself:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AG1").AutoFilter Field:=10, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(periodStart), _
            Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(periodEnd)
```

Now there's a catch when the dates in your Excel contain time parts: If your criteria contains only the date part, you would miss data with a timestamp of `periodEnd` with any time value (45107.75 is larger than 45107). So it's better to write

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AG1").AutoFilter Field:=10, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(periodStart), _
            Criteria2:="<" & CLng(periodEnd) + 1
```

---

And why is the filter working when you first run your code and then go to Excel and edit the Filter manually without modifying it? Your code writes strings (that looks like a date, but they are strings, not dates), so the filter will not find anything. If you open the filter editor, you see the strings that the macro wrote. When you press the OK button, Excel thinks that you freshly entered the criteria and converts it to the according numbers and the filter works.

Comment: The catch and the great finale. Wonderful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I applied syntax you gave me and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Between Dates

[image]

```vb
Sub FilterBetweenDates()

    Const DATE_COLUMN As Long = 1

    Dim PeriodStart As Date: PeriodStart = #7/1/2023# ' July 1st
    Dim PeriodEnd As Date: PeriodEnd = #12/31/2023# ' December 31st
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    rg.AutoFilter _
        Field:=DATE_COLUMN, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(PeriodStart), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(PeriodEnd)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified my code to include your procedure (adding column index and dates as variables and as suggested by FunThomas changing criteria2 as < enddate + 1).

It's working perfectly.
Sorry I already saw your procedure on other topics around filter dates but I didn't understood what append as I had the right dates appearing in my filter.