How to filter an excel date column using VBA?
I’m working on a VBA script in Excel that filters a range of cells and then prints the filtered rows. However, I’m encountering a runtime error and I’m not sure how to resolve it.
Date filtering : For the date filtering its supposed to only return row with dates from the previous day or the past 3 days if the current day is monday
so if today is friday the only rows visible should be from thursday and if its monday - sunday saturday and friday rows should appear (hope this makes sense)
VB script:
Set filterRange = srcSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

' Apply the filter
With filterRange
    If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then ' If today is Monday
        .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:=">=DATE(" & Year(Date - 3) & "," & Month(Date - 3) & "," & Day(Date - 3) & ")"
        .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria2:="<=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
    Else ' If today is any other day
        .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:="=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
    End If
    .AutoFilter Field:=statusColumnIndex, Criteria1:="LDP"
End With

' Copy the filtered data to the destination sheet
lastRow = filterRange.Resize(filterRange.Rows.Count - 1, filterRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Row
filterRange.Resize(lastRow - filterRange.Row + 1, filterRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy destSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Clear the filters
filterRange.AutoFilter

When I run this script, I get a runtime error on this line:
lastRow = filterRange.Resize(filterRange.Rows.Count - 1, filterRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Row

The error message is “Run-time error ‘1004’: No cells were found.”
However, when I print the number of visible rows to the debug console using
Debug.Print filterRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count,

I get 37, which suggests that the filter is working correctly and there are 37 visible rows.
But when I try to print the filtered rows using filterRange.PrintOut, it prints empty rows.
I’m not sure why I’m getting this error or why the PrintOut method isn’t printing the visible rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Apologies for the bad code its my first day learning and writing VB using AI of course ;D
here is the full script for reference:
Public Sub FilterAndWriteData()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim dateColumnIndex As Long
    Dim statusColumnIndex As Long
    Dim visibleRows As Long
    Dim rngVisible As Range

    ' Set the source and destination worksheets
    ' Check if the "FilteredSheet" exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilteredSheet")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If the "FilteredSheet" doesn't exist, create it
    If destSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        destSheet.Name = "FilteredSheet"
    End If

    ' Set the source worksheet
    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Find the column indices for date and status columns
    dateColumnIndex = srcSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Load Date", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    statusColumnIndex = srcSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Final Status", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

    ' Clear the destination sheet
    destSheet.UsedRange.Clear

    ' Set the filter range
    Set filterRange = srcSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    ' Apply the filter
    With filterRange
        If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then ' If today is Monday
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:=">=DATE(" & Year(Date - 3) & "," & Month(Date - 3) & "," & Day(Date - 3) & ")"
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria2:="<=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
        Else ' If today is any other day
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:="=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
        End If
        .AutoFilter Field:=statusColumnIndex, Criteria1:="LDP"
    End With

    visibleRows = filterRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
    Debug.Print "The size of the filtered data is: "; visibleRows

    ' Get the visible cells in filterRange
On Error Resume Next
Set rngVisible = filterRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
' Check if any visible cells were found
If Not rngVisible Is Nothing Then
    ' Print the visible cells
    rngVisible.PrintOut
Else
    MsgBox "No visible cells were found in the filter range."
End If

    ' Copy the filtered data to the destination sheet
    'lastRow = filterRange.Resize(filterRange.Rows.Count - 1, filterRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Row
    'filterRange.Resize(lastRow - filterRange.Row + 1, filterRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy destSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Clear the filters
    ' filterRange.AutoFilter
End Sub

I tried to filter using
With filterRange
        If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then ' If today is Monday
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:=">=DATE(" & Year(Date - 3) & "," & Month(Date - 3) & "," & Day(Date - 3) & ")"
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria2:="<=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
        Else ' If today is any other day
            .AutoFilter Field:=dateColumnIndex, Criteria1:="=DATE(" & Year(Date - 1) & "," & Month(Date - 1) & "," & Day(Date - 1) & ")"
        End If
        .AutoFilter Field:=statusColumnIndex, Criteria1:="LDP"
    End With

to filter by the columns and paste the results on a different sheet in the same workbook this is the overall aim of the script

Pass your date as long-value - esp. if you are on a non-englisch system. Look here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219141/16578424

Filter by Dates: Copy Recent Data
Issues

The filter criteria are wrong. I have used strings but you should also consider the easier way presented in the post suggested by Ike in your comments.
Although Range.Cells.Count returns the number of cells of any range, Range.Rows.Count or Range.Columns.Count return the number of rows or columns respectively only of the first area of the range (On the other hand, you can loop through the rows or columns of a non-contiguous (multi-area) range using a For Each...Next loop). Therefore I have used Intersect to reference the cells in the visible range's first column and Range.Cells.Count to retrieve the number of rows.
I have assumed you're also copying the headers since you're clearing the whole sheet and copying to cell A1. Therefore the On Error Resume Next used to set a range 'safely', isn't necessary i.e. the visible range will always have at least the header row.

A Quick Fix
Sub CopyRecentData()
    
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range, visibleRange As Range, destCell As Range
    Dim DateColumnIndex As Long, StatusColumnIndex As Long
    Dim VisibleRowsCount As Long
    Dim DateFormat As String, Yesterday As String, ThreeDaysAgo As String
    Dim WasSheetAutoFiltered As Boolean
    
    ' Set the source worksheet
    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If srcSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        srcSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        WasSheetAutoFiltered = True
    End If
    
    ' Find the column indices for date and status columns
    DateColumnIndex = srcSheet.Rows(1).Find( _
        What:="Load Date", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    StatusColumnIndex = srcSheet.Rows(1).Find( _
        What:="Final Status", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

    ' Set the filter range
    Set filterRange = srcSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    With filterRange
        ' Apply the filter
        DateFormat = "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
        Yesterday = Format(Date - 1, DateFormat)
        If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then ' If today is Monday
            ThreeDaysAgo = Format(Date - 3, DateFormat)
            .AutoFilter _
                Field:=DateColumnIndex, _
                Criteria1:=">=" & ThreeDaysAgo, _
                Operator:=xlAnd, _
                Criteria2:="<=" & Yesterday
        Else ' If today is any other day
            .AutoFilter Field:=DateColumnIndex, Criteria1:="=" & Yesterday
        End If
        .AutoFilter Field:=StatusColumnIndex, Criteria1:="LDP"
        ' Get the visible rows of filterRange (incl. header row)
        Set visibleRange = filterRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
        
    ' Clear filters
    If WasSheetAutoFiltered Then
        srcSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
        srcSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
        
    ' Check if only headers are visible.
    With visibleRange
        VisibleRowsCount = Intersect(.Cells, .Cells(1).EntireColumn).Cells.Count
        Debug.Print "The number of filtered rows (incl. headers) is: " _
            & VisibleRowsCount
        If VisibleRowsCount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No filtered data found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ' Set the destination sheet and first cell
    
    ' Check if the destination exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FilteredSheet")
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' If the destination doesn't exist, create it
    If destSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        destSheet.Name = "FilteredSheet"
    Else
        ' Clear the destination sheet
        destSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    End If
    ' Set the destination first cell.
    Set destCell = destSheet.Range("A1")

    ' Copy.
    
    visibleRange.Copy destCell
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Recent data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub

